# Hibernate interceptor for contextual sessions?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to write a Hibernate interceptor for auditing purpose, but one that will work with thread local contextual sessions (instead of me calling openSession() every time and passing it an interceptor object).

Any guidelines/sample code on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. (My main problem is to figure out a way to give interceptor object to a contextual session when it's opened for the very first time).

Answer (score 3):

if you use Hibernate only, you can set Interceptor for session with two approach.

```
//interceptor for global, set interceptor when create sessionFactory with Configure
sessionFactory =
  new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
    .setInterceptor(new AuditTrailInterceptor())
    .buildSessionFactory()

//interceptor for per Session
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(new XxxInterceptor())
```

if you use Spring to create SessionFactory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="entityInterceptor">
    <bean class="your.XxxInterceptor"/>
  </property>
  <!-- other  configuration -->
</bean>
```

I found one blog post which would help you. http://www.sleberknight.com/blog/sleberkn/entry/using_a_hibernate_interceptor_to

Comment: Yes, but in these cases the interceptor will be globally set, and the same interceptor object will be used for many sessions and hence will need to be thread-safe. So how do I do it for only some sessions which are thread local contextual sessions and set a different interceptor object per such session?

Answer (score 2):

why not using hibernate's audit sulotion? http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html

Comment: Thx for the link, I may use it. But I'm curious to see if an interceptor can be written for thread local contextual sessions.

Comment: you can use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` which is bind to current thread.

Comment: yes, but how do I pass it an instance of interceptor? I need to do it when the session is opened.